# View wrl file on debian

Tags: animation

I want to watch an wrl file (showing some physics object) in Debian

http://www.phys.ufl.edu/fermisurface/vrml2/Mo.wrl

**Does anyone know a way, how to watch it?**

All workarounds etc. are welcome

So far I tried:

- whitedune: most promissing, as it does not totally chrash, when opening the file
- freewrl: Segmentation fault after compilation on debian
- blender, meshlab, g3dviewer: import problems with wrl file
- openvrml-player: gives warning 'Browser creation failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openvrml/openvrml-xembed: Success' and crashes, when opening wrl file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install view3dscene

(As ROOT)

```
# apt install view3dscene
```

Comment: worked: thank you a lot!!! I will describe what was necessary in an other answer

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by arochester **view3dscene** does the job.

As an `apt-get install view3dscene` is not available under **Debian 'wheezy'** I finally ended up using the **binary** available on the [project homepage](https://castle-engine.sourceforge.io/view3dscene.php).

Select your system, download, extract, double click the view3dscene file.
Not everything works perfectly, but it is enough to turn the picture and make nice screenshots.